# Numpad forward slash to search without numpad?

Tags: search

In Vim I use the forward slash on my numpad a lot for searching. Thinking of getting a TKL keyboard I was wondering how that works without a numpad. I tried the forward slash on the regular keys, but that doesn't have the same effect.

Does anyone know how to make this work? 
I'm thinking rebinding the key in Vim would do the trick, but there must be a built-in solution I don't know.

Comment: The regular slash (the one next to the <SHIFT> key) should have the same effect as the numpad one.. What happens when you try to use it?

Comment: Nothing. I thought that should work too, but that's why I asked the question. I even tried switching the keyboard layout to qwerty, so I don't have to use the shift key to get a / on the BE azerty layout. No difference though.

Comment: Well that's really odd.. I don't thing the problem comes from vim, does the `/` works normally on your terminal outside of vim?

Comment: Does that still not work if you start Vim without a vimrc or plugins that disable this? I assume this difference is in GVim or similar, right? On the terminal you typically can't tell the slash from main keyboard from the one on keypad apart... Does the slash on keyboard work at all in insert mode? Or does it only not work in normal mode, to start a search?

Comment: Good idea. I tried loading GVim without any vimrc and it does work in that case. So I guess something is capturing that key for some reason. I'll have to investigate.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I had a mapping for "/" in there for some search plugin I'm not using anymore #facepalm